# Slower network on Windows VM in Virtualbox

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtualbox

I am running a Windows XP guest on Windows 7 host for browser compatibility testing.  However, this is introducing network performance artifacts.

Speedtest.net from host shows 4ms ping, 36MB/sec download and download

Same test from guest shows 7ms ping, 29MB/sec download and only 5MB/sec upload

The ping is actually what I'm most interested in improving.

Is there a network config change I could make to get closer to what I see on the host?

Answer (score 1):

assign direct connection by using usb network adapter instead of using NAT and borrowing internet from host.

Comment: I'm sorry, where do you set that option?  In the guest Control Panel?  In VirtualBox settings?

Comment: select your OS in guest, then click on settings, then go to network. change from NAT to host only. before that, u need to connect USB adapter to your virtualbox so your guest os can see the adapter